# How do I split a list of array?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Here is the list array:

```
{"things":{"1":"1_4","3":"3_13","4":"4_18","5":"5_25","6":"6_28","7":"7_32"}}
```

here is the code:

```
var t = things;
string aa = t[0].ToString();
```

How do I split the above array in , separator and _ .
from the above array i want only 1_4,3_13...this column and save in two different var.

when I am using

```
string[] ss = aa.Split(new char[] { ',', '|', }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

the problem is that in first list {"things":{"1":"1_4".
comes

so how to remove {"things"??

Comment: This looks like JSON. Have you looked at using something like Newtonsoft.Json to parse this?

Comment: yes..what should i do??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not parse JSON yourself. Do not reinvent the wheel.

You should define a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("things")]
    public Dictionary<int, string> Things { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize your string into an instance of `MyClass`

```
var rawData = "{\"things\":{\"1\":\"1_4\",\"3\":\"3_13\",\"4\":\"4_18\",\"5\":\"5_25\",\"6\":\"6_28\",\"7\":\"7_32\"}}";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(rawData);
```

Then you can use `data`

```
Console.WriteLine(data.Things[1]);
```

You should add Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package to your project and add `using Newtonsoft.Json` namespace to your code file.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of string manipulation, you should use JSON library like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Simply, because you are working with string in JSON format and it will be easier to work with that information if you deserialize it into proper `object` or `JObject`.

Example with `JObject`:

```
string json = @"{""things"":{""1"":""1_4"",""3"":""3_13"",""4"":""4_18"",""5"":""5_25"",""6"":""6_28"",""7"":""7_32""}}";
var jObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
var prop1 = jObj.GetValue("things").GetPropertyValue("1").ConvertTo<string>();
var prop4 = jObj.GetValue("things").GetPropertyValue("4").ConvertTo<string>();
```

Note: You can create classes which will represent your JSON structure, if you want to have strongly typed object structure.

Answer (score -1):

You should first split by `{` then discard the first and after that you are left with:

> "1":"1_4","3":"3_13","4":"4_18","5":"5_25","6":"6_28","7":"7_32"}}

Now you split with `,` and get

> "1":"1_4"
>
> "3":"3_13" and so on.

Then you split each with `:` and take the second one.

Only remember that the last one is `"7_32"}}` which you should remove the trailing `}}`

Like this:

```
var elems = aa.Split(new[] { '{' })[1].Split(new[] { ',' });
var res = elems.Select(obj => obj.Trim("}".ToCharArray()).Split(new[] { ':' }));
```

Hope this is what you want :)

Comment: last element coming with "10_48"}}

Comment: how do i hide }}

Comment: Well `Trim('}')` should have done it but if it doesn't try `Trim("}}")`

Comment: var t = things;
            string aa = t[0].ToString();
          
            string[] ss = aa.Split(new char[] { ',', '{', }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
           
           
            string[] arr = ss.Skip(1).ToArray();
            var ress= arr.Select(obj => obj.Split(new[] { ':' }));

Comment: I get it. Your code seems a little problematic. Use my template. It will remove the `}}`

Comment: How is that not working? All right if you want change your own code like this: `arr.Select(obj => obj.Split(new[] { ':' }).Trim('}'));`

Comment: string[] doesnot contain a defination for Trim method

Comment: here i am getting both in string{2} string{0}"1":string{1}"1_4"

Comment: i want only string1 element i.e. 1_4

Comment: where should i change??

Comment: why should i use skip(1)??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139720/discussion-between-emad-and-manoj).